# Know how transfer of a framework (Eclipse Plugin Development and Debugging - How to find out what's going on?)

Tags: debugging, eclipse-plugin, uml, knowledge-management

I've just been talking to a very! frustrated co-worker of mine, I'm looking for advice instead of him :-)
He is maintaining a complex eclipse plugin (actually rather an application) and he has no clue what is going on when he e.g. clicks a list. The external developer who created it used reflections and listeners and it is kinda hard / impossible for him to find out what is actually triggered when he clicks a link. He started renaming the functions to see whether he gets an error when he clicks on the list (works thanks to reflection). 
On some lists he gets it (which is correct), on some, he does not.
Is there something which would help getting these kind of problems solved? 
Any ideas would help: 
Tools (UML?), tricks, or even what he should be doing when he gets the next chance to speak to the external programmer. 
Just makes me sad seeing him grow grey hair because of that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used a trick which was to launch and Eclipse application directly from the workspace. I then clicked on graphical interfaces and looked at the logfile. It was really a nightmare and an incredible waste of time but it did the job.

Good luck because you will need few months just to understand what is going on inside this program !!

Comment: He didn't know about it. It is a logfile with all calls or just the sysouts he introduced?